# I need to add a foreign key to Phinx DB migration but it's getting error

Tags: php, database-migration, phinx

I want to add a foreign key to phinx Db migration but it's getting an error.

I want to use camping_id in the Bids table as a foreign key from the id of the campaigns table.

```
 public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('bids');
        $table ->addColumn("value", "integer", ["limit" => 11])
            ->addColumn("camping_id", "integer", ["limit" => 45])
            ->addColumn("subscriber_id","integer", ["limit" => 11])
            ->addColumn("added_date", "datetime")
            ->addColumn("deleted", "boolean", ["null" => true])
            ->addColumn("msisdn", "string", ["limit" => 100], ["null" => true])
            ->addColumn("program_id", "integer", ["limit" => 11], ["null" => true])
            ->addColumn("status", "string", ["limit" => 45], ["null" => true])
            ->addForeignKey(['camping_id', 'id'],
                'campaigns',
                ['camping_id', 'id'],
                ['delete'=> 'NO_ACTION', 'update'=> 'NO_ACTION', 'constraint' => 'camping_id'])
            ->create();

    }
```

after running the migration, I got this error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in /var/www/git/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php:167
Stack trace:
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. You should have to migrate the parent tables first because of the reference columns should exist before executing the foreign key related migrations.